# Reducing voltage for solid state relay

Tags: resistance, buck, solid-state-relay, zener

I have a solid state relay which wants a 1.25-2.5V "activation" input, but my output from the micro controller is 5V. Is it possible to use a zener diode for this? Or do I need a buck converter? I don't know how small/big the resistance or current through the relay is, but if I knew that I could perhaps use a parallel resistor with a lower resistance? Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Please give us the part number for the SSR and, preferably, a link to the datasheet. The answer is probably a voltage divider (2 resistors) but I cannot be sure until I see the specifics of the SSR.

Comment: A part number for the microcontroller would also be useful.

Comment: Most industrial SSRs will accept 3-32VDC input. If it's a 'bare' LED input it might just need a series resistor. It's important to know the current and voltage requirements, so a link is the only way to give a reliable answer.

Comment: You would pretty much never use a buck regulator to drop down input voltages. Too much latency for most applications! Use a linear voltage regulator (like LM1117) or a voltage divider. Or, if you have a 2.5V supply, use transistors or FETs with the base / gate driven by the microcontroller and the collector / source fed by the 2.5V supply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solid state relays generally have LEDs on the input side.  Sometimes they have resistors in series with these LEDs, sometimes not.  Depending on the current requirement, you can drive the SSR input directly with the microcontroller output and a series resistor.  Ultimately LEDs run on current, and have a fairly predictable voltage accross them when doing so.  A resistor in series with a LED to allow driving it from a higher voltage is perfectly legitimate.

If the microcontroller output can't source or sink (the SSR input can be between power and the micro) enough current, then you have to use a transistor somehow anyway.  The simplest is:

[image]

You have to look in the relay datasheet to see how much voltage the LED drops, what current it is intended to be run at, and what the value of the internal resistor in series with the LED is, if any.  Then it's easy to determine the value of R1.

For example, let's say the LED requires 10 mA to operate the relay, drops 1.2 V in the process, and the internal resistor is 100 Ω.  The emitter of Q1 will be about 4.3 V when the digital output is high, so that leaves 4.3V - 1.2V = 3.1V for the combined resistance to drop.  3.1V / 10mA = 310 Ω, which is what the combined resistance should be.  100 Ω of that is already inside the relay, so R1 should be 210 Ω.  The common value of 200 Ω would be good, and definitely provide for the 10 mA.  SSRs usually have wide latitude in the allowed LED current.  However, don't guess, look at the datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the solid state relay needs about 10-50mA you can use the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIPfTz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is a NPN transistor used as an emitter follower. I have used a voltage divider to feed the base with 3v (about 3mA load for the mcu pin). The emitter voltage will be 3v-0.6v = about 2.4v.

The resistors can be resized based on the needed output current (keeping in mind the max current that the control device can provide).
You can also change the relation between the two resistors if you want a lower output voltage.

Using this configuration rather than a simple voltage divider will require less current from the control source (in case it is an mcu with limited current output ability).

*p.s. I didn't find an SSR component in circuit lab so I used a normal relay, SSR doesn't have a coil input*